# .Net core 2.0 en Visual Studio 2017 version 15.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

comencé a ver unos videos para desarrollar aplicaciones web con .net, estoy utilizando Visual Studio 2017 version 15.0, en los videos utilizan el core 2.0 para acceder a una plantilla MVC.
Con esta versión del Visual Studio solo tengo acceso al core 1.0 y 1.1 y en ninguna está la opción de MVC.
Existe alguna forma de agregarle el core 2.0 a esta versión de Visual Studio?
Preferiría no tener que instalar otra versión del Visual Studio, gracias

Comment: Y si usas el CLI de .NET Core?

Comment: Según lo que he estao leyendo el CLI .NET Core es para versiones de visual studio superiores a la que mencioné que tengo, me pide intalar 15.3.0 o superior

Comment: No necesitas VS para usar el CLI, te basta con un terminal de powershell o cmd.

Comment: Echale un ojo a este enlace: https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started-with-dotnet-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Si, creo que necesitas actualizar visual studio a la versión 15.3 o superior, y mirar que en los complementos esté .net core 2.